# How to do this in flutter

Tags: flutter, slider, timeslots

[image: Time slot with sliding option]

This a time slot picker for booking meeting rooms, I want to show the booked times and select (from the available times) the start time and end time by sliding

Comment: can you please share code what you had tried so far

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @AhmadRaza
I did not implement this yet i just want know the idea or how to start implementing this